# How to draw squares instead of circles in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How can I draw square instead of circle on LineChart in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)?

Answer (score 1):

`LineChart` only supports circles.

But a solution could be to combine `Line-` and `ScatterChart` in a `CombinedChart`.

- use `ScatterChart` to draw the squares
- use `LineChart` without circles to draw the lines

Example of `CombinedChart` [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java).

Comment: and how do you disable the circles?

Comment: data.setDrawCircles(false); where data is of type LineDataSet